# Don't display post if title contains specific words Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

is there a way that a stop displaying posts in the loop if title contains specific words?

My code is like this:

```
<?php if(strpos(get_the_title(), 'Product1', 'Product2') === false) { } ?>
```

With this code my posts does not have title at all.

Comment: Good to refer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/270141/is-there-a-way-to-conditionally-check-whether-a-wordpress-post-title-is-empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check to contain words by using regex.

```
if (!preg_match('/(word1|word2|word3)/', get_the_title()) {
  // title doesn't contain word1, word2, word3
}
```

To make case insensitive add the flag 'i' in the regex.

```
'/(word1|word2|word3)/i'
```